# org.apache.xml.serializer.ToXMLSAXHandler cannot be cast to org.apache.xml.serializer.SerializationHandler

Tags: jboss6.x

I'm using JBoss6 M5 and jdk1.6-22.
When I try to run the server, I get the deployment error. Does anyone have any clues on what could be the problem? Thx!

> Deployment "vfs:///mnt/data/programming/rz/server/server/default/deploy/psuite-metadata.war" is in error due to the following reason(s): org.apache.xml.serializer.utils.WrappedRuntimeException: org.apache.xml.serializer.ToXMLSAXHandler cannot be cast to org.apache.xml.serializer.SerializationHandler

---

Here is the full stack trace:

```
17:50:45,297 ERROR [AbstractKernelController] Error installing to Real: name=vfs:///mnt/data/programming/rz/server/server/default/deploy/psuite-metadata.war state=PreReal mode=Manual requiredState=Real: org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException: Error during deploy: vfs:///mnt/data/programming/rz/server/server/default/deploy/psuite-metadata.war
        at org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException.rethrowAsDeploymentException(DeploymentException.java:49) [:2.2.0.Alpha7]
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:185) [:2.2.0.Alpha7]
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doDeploy(DeployersImpl.java:1832) [:2.2.0.Alpha7]
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1550) [:2.2.0.Alpha7]
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.install(DeployersImpl.java:1491) [:2.2.0.Alpha7]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:379) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.Alpha10]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:2044) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.Alpha10]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:1083) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.Alpha10]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.executeOrIncrementStateDirectly(AbstractController.java:1322) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.Alpha10]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1246) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.Alpha10]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1139) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.Alpha10]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:939) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.Alpha10]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:654) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.Alpha10]
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.change(DeployersImpl.java:1983) [:2.2.0.Alpha7]
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.process(DeployersImpl.java:1076) [:2.2.0.Alpha7]
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.process(MainDeployerImpl.java:679) [:2.2.0.Alpha7]
        at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.deployers.MainDeployerPlugin.process(MainDeployerPlugin.java:106) [:6.0.0.20100911-M5]
        at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileControllerContext$DelegateDeployer.process(ProfileControllerContext.java:130) [:0.1.0.Alpha1]
        at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileDeployAction.deploy(ProfileDeployAction.java:148) [:0.1.0.Alpha1]
        at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileDeployAction.installActionInternal(ProfileDeployAction.java:94) [:0.1.0.Alpha1]
        at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.InstallsAwareAction.installAction(InstallsAwareAction.java:54) [jboss-kernel.jar:2.2.0.Alpha10]
        at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.InstallsAwareAction.installAction(InstallsAwareAction.java:42) [jboss-kernel.jar:2.2.0.Alpha10]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.SimpleControllerContextAction.simpleInstallAction(SimpleControllerContextAction.java:62) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.Alpha10]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.AccessControllerContextAction.install(AccessControllerContextAction.java:71) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.Alpha10]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContextActions.install(AbstractControllerContextActions.java:51) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.Alpha10]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:379) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.Alpha10]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:2044) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.Alpha10]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:1083) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.Alpha10]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.executeOrIncrementStateDirectly(AbstractController.java:1322) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.Alpha10]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1246) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.Alpha10]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1139) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.Alpha10]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:939) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.Alpha10]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:654) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.Alpha10]
        at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileServiceController.activate(ProfileServiceController.java:188) [:0.1.0.Alpha1]
        at org.jboss.profileservice.AbstractProfileService.activateProfile(AbstractProfileService.java:170) [:0.1.0.Alpha1]
        at org.jboss.profileservice.bootstrap.AbstractProfileServiceBootstrap.activate(AbstractProfileServiceBootstrap.java:117) [:0.1.0.Alpha1]
        at org.jboss.profileservice.resolver.BasicResolverFactory$ProfileResolverFacade.deploy(BasicResolverFactory.java:89) [:0.1.0.Alpha1]
        at org.jboss.profileservice.bootstrap.AbstractProfileServiceBootstrap.start(AbstractProfileServiceBootstrap.java:97) [:0.1.0.Alpha1]
        at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.bootstrap.BasicProfileServiceBootstrap.start(BasicProfileServiceBootstrap.java:130) [:6.0.0.20100911-M5]
        at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.bootstrap.BasicProfileServiceBootstrap.start(BasicProfileServiceBootstrap.java:56) [:6.0.0.20100911-M5]
        at org.jboss.bootstrap.impl.base.server.AbstractServer.startBootstraps(AbstractServer.java:827) [jboss-bootstrap-impl-base.jar:2.1.0-alpha-5]
        at org.jboss.bootstrap.impl.base.server.AbstractServer$StartServerTask.run(AbstractServer.java:417) [jboss-bootstrap-impl-base.jar:2.1.0-alpha-5]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [:1.6.0_22]
Caused by: org.apache.xml.serializer.utils.WrappedRuntimeException: org.apache.xml.serializer.ToXMLSAXHandler cannot be cast to org.apache.xml.serializer.SerializationHandler
        at org.apache.xml.serializer.SerializerFactory.getSerializer(SerializerFactory.java:179) [:2.7.1]
        at org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerIdentityImpl.createResultContentHandler(TransformerIdentityImpl.java:260) [:6.0.0.20100911-M5]
        at org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerIdentityImpl.transform(TransformerIdentityImpl.java:330) [:6.0.0.20100911-M5]
        at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.SchemaSerializer.writeXml(SchemaSerializer.java:59) [:2.2.10]
        at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.SchemaSerializer.marshall(SchemaSerializer.java:49) [:2.2.10]
        at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLWriterImpl.printExtensibilityElements(Unknown Source) [:1.6]
        at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLWriterImpl.printTypes(Unknown Source) [:1.6]
        at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLWriterImpl.printDefinition(Unknown Source) [:1.6]
        at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLWriterImpl.writeWSDL(Unknown Source) [:1.6]
        at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLWriterImpl.getDocument(Unknown Source) [:1.6]
        at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.deployment.WSDLFilePublisher.getWsdlDocument(WSDLFilePublisher.java:112) [:3.4.0.Beta2]
        at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.deployment.WSDLFilePublisher.publishWsdlFiles(WSDLFilePublisher.java:78) [:3.4.0.Beta2]
        at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.deployment.EndpointImpl.publishContractToFilesystem(EndpointImpl.java:84) [:3.4.0.Beta2]
        at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.deployment.EndpointImpl.doPublish(EndpointImpl.java:66) [:3.4.0.Beta2]
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.publish(EndpointImpl.java:234) [:2.2.10]
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.publish(EndpointImpl.java:477) [:2.2.10]
        at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.configuration.NonSpringBusHolder.configure(NonSpringBusHolder.java:102) [:3.4.0.Beta2]
        at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.deployment.aspect.BusDeploymentAspect.start(BusDeploymentAspect.java:98) [:3.4.0.Beta2]
        at org.jboss.webservices.integration.deployers.WSDeploymentAspectDeployer.internalDeploy(WSDeploymentAspectDeployer.java:114) [:6.0.0.20100911-M5]
        at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractRealDeployer.deploy(AbstractRealDeployer.java:55) [:2.2.0.Alpha7]
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:179) [:2.2.0.Alpha7]
```

Comment: solved, i needed to move xalan.jar to the jboss-X/lib/endorsed

Comment: probably good if you move your comment to an answer..  and thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 4):

Move xalan.jar to the jboss-X/lib/endorsed