# Exporting PDF Docx4j error

Tags: jboss, apache-fop, docx4j, xalan

I'm getting this kind of error, which I don't know how to treat. I guess Xalan, Serializer are responsible but I must have them inside my Jboss module to let everything work fine. 
Please give me some hint.

```
12:26:48,832 SEVERE [org.apache.fop.area.AreaTreeModel] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-6) Error while rendering page 1: org.apache.xml.serializer.utils.WrappedRuntimeException: org.apache.xml.serializer.ToXMLSAXHandler cannot be cast to org.apache.xml.serializer.SerializationHandler
    at org.apache.xml.serializer.SerializerFactory.getSerializer(SerializerFactory.java:179) [serializer-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerIdentityImpl.createResultContentHandler(TransformerIdentityImpl.java:260) [xalan-2.7.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerIdentityImpl.startDocument(TransformerIdentityImpl.java:909) [xalan-2.7.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.xmlgraphics.xmp.XMPSerializer.writeXML(XMPSerializer.java:89) [xmlgraphics-commons-1.5.jar:1.5]
    at org.apache.xmlgraphics.xmp.XMPSerializer.writeXMPPacket(XMPSerializer.java:69) [xmlgraphics-commons-1.5.jar:1.5]
    at org.apache.fop.pdf.PDFMetadata.outputRawStreamData(PDFMetadata.java:92) [fop-1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.fop.pdf.AbstractPDFStream.encodeAndWriteStream(AbstractPDFStream.java:196) [fop-1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.fop.pdf.AbstractPDFStream.output(AbstractPDFStream.java:239) [fop-1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.fop.pdf.PDFStream.output(PDFStream.java:158) [fop-1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.fop.pdf.PDFMetadata.output(PDFMetadata.java:84) [fop-1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.fop.pdf.PDFDocument.outputIndirectObject(PDFDocument.java:951) [fop-1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.fop.pdf.PDFDocument.streamIndirectObject(PDFDocument.java:918) [fop-1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.fop.pdf.PDFDocument.output(PDFDocument.java:912) [fop-1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.fop.render.pdf.PDFContentGenerator.flushPDFDoc(PDFContentGenerator.java:141) [fop-1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.fop.render.pdf.PDFPainter.flushPDFDoc(PDFPainter.java:210) [fop-1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.fop.render.pdf.PDFPainter.drawImage(PDFPainter.java:151) [fop-1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.fop.render.intermediate.IFRenderer.drawImage(IFRenderer.java:1272) [fop-1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.fop.render.intermediate.IFRenderer.renderImage(IFRenderer.java:1259) [fop-1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.fop.render.AbstractRenderer.renderInlineViewport(AbstractRenderer.java:816) [fop-1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.fop.render.AbstractPathOrientedRenderer.renderInlineViewport(AbstractPathOrientedRenderer.java:785) [fop-1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.fop.render.intermediate.IFRenderer.renderInlineViewport(IFRenderer.java:866) [fop-1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.fop.render.AbstractRenderer.renderInlineArea(AbstractRenderer.java:678) [fop-1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.fop.render.intermediate.IFRenderer.renderInlineArea(IFRenderer.java:913) [fop-1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.fop.render.AbstractRenderer.renderInlineParent(AbstractRenderer.java:781) [fop-1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.fop.render.intermediate.IFRenderer.renderInlineParent(IFRenderer.java:930) [fop-1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.fop.render.AbstractRenderer.renderInlineArea(AbstractRenderer.java:672) [fop-1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.fop.render.intermediate.IFRenderer.renderInlineArea(IFRenderer.java:913) [fop-1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.fop.render.AbstractRenderer.renderLineArea(AbstractRenderer.java:643) [fop-1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.fop.render.AbstractRenderer.renderBlocks(AbstractRenderer.java:561) [fop-1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.fop.render.AbstractRenderer.renderBlock(AbstractRenderer.java:598) [fop-1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.fop.render.intermediate.IFRenderer.renderBlock(IFRenderer.java:980) [fop-1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.fop.render.AbstractRenderer.renderBlocks(AbstractRenderer.java:546) [fop-1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.fop.render.AbstractRenderer.renderRegion(AbstractRenderer.java:337) [fop-1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.fop.render.AbstractRenderer.renderRegionViewport(AbstractRenderer.java:301) [fop-1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.fop.render.intermediate.IFRenderer.renderRegionViewport(IFRenderer.java:748) [fop-1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.fop.render.AbstractRenderer.renderPageAreas(AbstractRenderer.java:257) [fop-1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.fop.render.AbstractRenderer.renderPage(AbstractRenderer.java:238) [fop-1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.fop.render.intermediate.IFRenderer.renderPage(IFRenderer.java:597) [fop-1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.fop.area.RenderPagesModel.addPage(RenderPagesModel.java:123) [fop-1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.fop.layoutmgr.AbstractPageSequenceLayoutManager.finishPage(AbstractPageSequenceLayoutManager.java:312) [fop-1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.fop.layoutmgr.PageSequenceLayoutManager.finishPage(PageSequenceLayoutManager.java:191) [fop-1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.fop.layoutmgr.AbstractPageSequenceLayoutManager.makeNewPage(AbstractPageSequenceLayoutManager.java:283) [fop-1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.fop.layoutmgr.PageSequenceLayoutManager.makeNewPage(PageSequenceLayoutManager.java:151) [fop-1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.fop.layoutmgr.PageBreaker.handleBreakTrait(PageBreaker.java:545) [fop-1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.fop.layoutmgr.PageBreaker.startPart(PageBreaker.java:444) [fop-1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.fop.layoutmgr.AbstractBreaker.addAreas(AbstractBreaker.java:530) [fop-1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.fop.layoutmgr.AbstractBreaker.addAreas(AbstractBreaker.java:481) [fop-1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.fop.layoutmgr.PageBreaker.doPhase3(PageBreaker.java:313) [fop-1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.fop.layoutmgr.AbstractBreaker.doLayout(AbstractBreaker.java:436) [fop-1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.fop.layoutmgr.PageBreaker.doLayout(PageBreaker.java:90) [fop-1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.fop.layoutmgr.PageSequenceLayoutManager.activateLayout(PageSequenceLayoutManager.java:113) [fop-1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.fop.area.AreaTreeHandler.endPageSequence(AreaTreeHandler.java:267) [fop-1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.fop.fo.pagination.PageSequence.endOfNode(PageSequence.java:128) [fop-1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.fop.fo.FOTreeBuilder$MainFOHandler.endElement(FOTreeBuilder.java:347) [fop-1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.fop.fo.FOTreeBuilder.endElement(FOTreeBuilder.java:181) [fop-1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerIdentityImpl.endElement(TransformerIdentityImpl.java:1102) [xalan-2.7.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:596)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:673)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1645)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:324)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:845)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:768)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:108)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1196)
    at __redirected.__XMLReaderFactory.parse(__XMLReaderFactory.java:180) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerIdentityImpl.transform(TransformerIdentityImpl.java:485) [xalan-2.7.1.jar:]
    at org.docx4j.convert.out.fo.renderers.FORendererApacheFOP.render(FORendererApacheFOP.java:211) [docx4j-3.2.1.jar:]
    at org.docx4j.convert.out.fo.renderers.FORendererApacheFOP.render(FORendererApacheFOP.java:158) [docx4j-3.2.1.jar:]
    at org.docx4j.convert.out.fo.AbstractFOExporter.postprocess(AbstractFOExporter.java:139) [docx4j-3.2.1.jar:]
    at org.docx4j.convert.out.fo.AbstractFOExporter.postprocess(AbstractFOExporter.java:47) [docx4j-3.2.1.jar:]
    at org.docx4j.convert.out.common.AbstractExporter.export(AbstractExporter.java:81) [docx4j-3.2.1.jar:]
    at org.docx4j.Docx4J.toFO(Docx4J.java:467) [docx4j-3.2.1.jar:]
    at it.led.neti.componenti.stampa.docx.StampaPolizzaXML.docx2PDF(StampaPolizzaXML.java:88) [classes:]
    at it.led.neti.componenti.stampa.docx.StampaPolizzaXML.injectXML(StampaPolizzaXML.java:116) [classes:]
    at it.led.neti.componenti.stampa.servlet.GestioneStampaServlet.submit(GestioneStampaServlet.java:485) [classes:]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at it.led.neti.common.servlet.GenericServlet.doPost(GenericServlet.java:126) [classes:]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.0.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.0.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:295) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
    at it.sacebt.neti.servlet.IECompatibilityFilter.doFilter(IECompatibilityFilter.java:27) [classes:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
    at it.led.neti.common.logutente.LogUtenteFilter.doFilter(LogUtenteFilter.java:44) [classes:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:231) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:149) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.jboss.security.negotiation.NegotiationAuthenticator$WrapperValve.invoke(NegotiationAuthenticator.java:491) [jboss-negotiation-common-2.3.3.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.3.3.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:420) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:169) [jboss-as-web-7.4.0.Final-redhat-19.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:145) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:97) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:344) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:856) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:653) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:926) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]

12:26:48,894 ERROR [org.docx4j.convert.out.common.AbstractExporter] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-6) Exception exporting package: org.apache.xml.serializer.utils.WrappedRuntimeException: org.apache.xml.serializer.ToXMLSAXHandler cannot be cast to org.apache.xml.serializer.SerializationHandler
    at org.apache.xml.serializer.SerializerFactory.getSerializer(SerializerFactory.java:179) [serializer-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerIdentityImpl.createResultContentHandler(TransformerIdentityImpl.java:260) [xalan-2.7.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerIdentityImpl.startDocument(TransformerIdentityImpl.java:909) [xalan-2.7.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.xmlgraphics.xmp.XMPSerializer.writeXML(XMPSerializer.java:89) [xmlgraphics-commons-1.5.jar:1.5]
    at org.apache.xmlgraphics.xmp.XMPSerializer.writeXMPPacket(XMPSerializer.java:69) [xmlgraphics-commons-1.5.jar:1.5]
    at org.apache.fop.pdf.PDFMetadata.outputRawStreamData(PDFMetadata.java:92) [fop-1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.fop.pdf.AbstractPDFStream.encodeAndWriteStream(AbstractPDFStream.java:196) [fop-1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.fop.pdf.AbstractPDFStream.output(AbstractPDFStream.java:239) [fop-1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.fop.pdf.PDFStream.output(PDFStream.java:158) [fop-1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.fop.pdf.PDFMetadata.output(PDFMetadata.java:84) [fop-1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.fop.pdf.PDFDocument.outputIndirectObject(PDFDocument.java:951) [fop-1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.fop.pdf.PDFDocument.streamIndirectObject(PDFDocument.java:918) [fop-1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.fop.pdf.PDFDocument.output(PDFDocument.java:912) [fop-1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.fop.render.pdf.PDFContentGenerator.flushPDFDoc(PDFContentGenerator.java:141) [fop-1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.fop.render.pdf.PDFPainter.flushPDFDoc(PDFPainter.java:210) [fop-1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.fop.render.pdf.PDFPainter.drawImage(PDFPainter.java:151) [fop-1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.fop.render.intermediate.IFRenderer.drawImage(IFRenderer.java:1272) [fop-1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.fop.render.intermediate.IFRenderer.renderImage(IFRenderer.java:1259) [fop-1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.fop.render.AbstractRenderer.renderInlineViewport(AbstractRenderer.java:816) [fop-1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.fop.render.AbstractPathOrientedRenderer.renderInlineViewport(AbstractPathOrientedRenderer.java:785) [fop-1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.fop.render.intermediate.IFRenderer.renderInlineViewport(IFRenderer.java:866) [fop-1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.fop.render.AbstractRenderer.renderInlineArea(AbstractRenderer.java:678) [fop-1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.fop.render.intermediate.IFRenderer.renderInlineArea(IFRenderer.java:913) [fop-1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.fop.render.AbstractRenderer.renderInlineParent(AbstractRenderer.java:781) [fop-1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.fop.render.intermediate.IFRenderer.renderInlineParent(IFRenderer.java:930) [fop-1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.fop.render.AbstractRenderer.renderInlineArea(AbstractRenderer.java:672) [fop-1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.fop.render.intermediate.IFRenderer.renderInlineArea(IFRenderer.java:913) [fop-1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.fop.render.AbstractRenderer.renderLineArea(AbstractRenderer.java:643) [fop-1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.fop.render.AbstractRenderer.renderBlocks(AbstractRenderer.java:561) [fop-1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.fop.render.AbstractRenderer.renderBlock(AbstractRenderer.java:598) [fop-1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.fop.render.intermediate.IFRenderer.renderBlock(IFRenderer.java:980) [fop-1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.fop.render.AbstractRenderer.renderBlocks(AbstractRenderer.java:546) [fop-1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.fop.render.AbstractRenderer.renderRegion(AbstractRenderer.java:337) [fop-1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.fop.render.AbstractRenderer.renderRegionViewport(AbstractRenderer.java:301) [fop-1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.fop.render.intermediate.IFRenderer.renderRegionViewport(IFRenderer.java:748) [fop-1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.fop.render.AbstractRenderer.renderPageAreas(AbstractRenderer.java:257) [fop-1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.fop.render.AbstractRenderer.renderPage(AbstractRenderer.java:238) [fop-1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.fop.render.intermediate.IFRenderer.renderPage(IFRenderer.java:597) [fop-1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.fop.area.RenderPagesModel.addPage(RenderPagesModel.java:123) [fop-1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.fop.layoutmgr.AbstractPageSequenceLayoutManager.finishPage(AbstractPageSequenceLayoutManager.java:312) [fop-1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.fop.layoutmgr.PageSequenceLayoutManager.finishPage(PageSequenceLayoutManager.java:191) [fop-1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.fop.layoutmgr.AbstractPageSequenceLayoutManager.makeNewPage(AbstractPageSequenceLayoutManager.java:283) [fop-1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.fop.layoutmgr.PageSequenceLayoutManager.makeNewPage(PageSequenceLayoutManager.java:151) [fop-1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.fop.layoutmgr.PageBreaker.handleBreakTrait(PageBreaker.java:545) [fop-1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.fop.layoutmgr.PageBreaker.startPart(PageBreaker.java:444) [fop-1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.fop.layoutmgr.AbstractBreaker.addAreas(AbstractBreaker.java:530) [fop-1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.fop.layoutmgr.AbstractBreaker.addAreas(AbstractBreaker.java:481) [fop-1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.fop.layoutmgr.PageBreaker.doPhase3(PageBreaker.java:313) [fop-1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.fop.layoutmgr.AbstractBreaker.doLayout(AbstractBreaker.java:436) [fop-1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.fop.layoutmgr.PageBreaker.doLayout(PageBreaker.java:90) [fop-1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.fop.layoutmgr.PageSequenceLayoutManager.activateLayout(PageSequenceLayoutManager.java:113) [fop-1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.fop.area.AreaTreeHandler.endPageSequence(AreaTreeHandler.java:267) [fop-1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.fop.fo.pagination.PageSequence.endOfNode(PageSequence.java:128) [fop-1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.fop.fo.FOTreeBuilder$MainFOHandler.endElement(FOTreeBuilder.java:347) [fop-1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.fop.fo.FOTreeBuilder.endElement(FOTreeBuilder.java:181) [fop-1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerIdentityImpl.endElement(TransformerIdentityImpl.java:1102) [xalan-2.7.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:596)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:673)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1645)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:324)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:845)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:768)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:108)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1196)
    at __redirected.__XMLReaderFactory.parse(__XMLReaderFactory.java:180) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerIdentityImpl.transform(TransformerIdentityImpl.java:485) [xalan-2.7.1.jar:]
    at org.docx4j.convert.out.fo.renderers.FORendererApacheFOP.render(FORendererApacheFOP.java:211) [docx4j-3.2.1.jar:]
    at org.docx4j.convert.out.fo.renderers.FORendererApacheFOP.render(FORendererApacheFOP.java:158) [docx4j-3.2.1.jar:]
    at org.docx4j.convert.out.fo.AbstractFOExporter.postprocess(AbstractFOExporter.java:139) [docx4j-3.2.1.jar:]
    at org.docx4j.convert.out.fo.AbstractFOExporter.postprocess(AbstractFOExporter.java:47) [docx4j-3.2.1.jar:]
    at org.docx4j.convert.out.common.AbstractExporter.export(AbstractExporter.java:81) [docx4j-3.2.1.jar:]
    at org.docx4j.Docx4J.toFO(Docx4J.java:467) [docx4j-3.2.1.jar:]
    at it.led.neti.componenti.stampa.docx.StampaPolizzaXML.docx2PDF(StampaPolizzaXML.java:88) [classes:]
    at it.led.neti.componenti.stampa.docx.StampaPolizzaXML.injectXML(StampaPolizzaXML.java:116) [classes:]
    at it.led.neti.componenti.stampa.servlet.GestioneStampaServlet.submit(GestioneStampaServlet.java:485) [classes:]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at it.led.neti.common.servlet.GenericServlet.doPost(GenericServlet.java:126) [classes:]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.0.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.0.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:295) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
    at it.sacebt.neti.servlet.IECompatibilityFilter.doFilter(IECompatibilityFilter.java:27) [classes:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
    at it.led.neti.common.logutente.LogUtenteFilter.doFilter(LogUtenteFilter.java:44) [classes:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:231) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:149) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.jboss.security.negotiation.NegotiationAuthenticator$WrapperValve.invoke(NegotiationAuthenticator.java:491) [jboss-negotiation-common-2.3.3.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.3.3.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:420) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:169) [jboss-as-web-7.4.0.Final-redhat-19.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:145) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:97) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:344) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:856) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:653) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:926) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
```

Comment: Which JBoss?  Try removing xalan serializer-2.7.1.jar from your war?  See  https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBEAP-19 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4347964/org-apache-xml-serializer-toxmlsaxhandler-cannot-be-cast-to-org-apache-xml-seria and http://www.docx4java.org/forums/docx-java-f6/opendopeintegrity-nullpointerexception-t2035.html

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'm running on JBoss EAP 6.3.0.GA (AS 7.4.0.Final-redhat-19). I've solved this issue by removing the Xalan and Serializer jars from the module already present in module/system/layers/base/org/apache folder in Jboss. Then I put Xalan as a dependency in the Docx4j module , positioned in module/system/layers/base/org. But now I'm stuck on other issues :')

Comment: Glad you've solved this; you should  copy your comment into an answer, and mark it as the answer.

Comment: @JasonPlutext: Jason please help me with this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32474158/docx4j-issues-converting-to-pdf

Comment: Please see docx4j guidelines on cross posting at http://www.docx4java.org/forums/announces/stackoverflow-t1088.html  and consider deleting one or the other.  In this case, its more a FOP question  (since you could post the intermediate XSL FO, and remove docx4j from the equation), so maybe SO is a better place for your post than the docx4j forums.

Comment: Sorry for that. I'll fix this.